# How to compress PNG image fetched from url without changing it's dimenstions

Tags: python, image, google-app-engine

I'm trying to save picture to datastore from url. Unfortunately my app came across fairly small PNG file that is > 1MB.

It would be ok to change forma to JPG

```
def save_image_from_url(url):
    image = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()

    if len(image)>1000000:
        # MAKE FILESIZE <1MB
        # WITHOUT CHANGING DIMENSTIONS

    picture = classes.Pictures(picture=image)
    picture.put()

    return str(picture.key.id())
```

**EDIT:** I would prefer to use `from google.appengine.api import images`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

```
images.crop(image, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, output_encoding=images.JPEG)
```

This should crop it to the original size and transform it to a JPEG at 85% quality, *(if I have got the order of the 0.0 and 1.0 values right)*.

Comment: Yes, that seems more cost effective. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured it out.

```
if len(image)>1000000:
    temp = images.Image(image)
    image = images.resize(
        image, 
        width=temp.width, 
        output_encoding=images.JPEG, 
        quality=80
    )
```

Comment: filesize reduction 90%